# Что есть программное обеспечение, веб-сайты являются программным обеспечением?

Tags: веб-программирование

Возможно, это несколько философский вопрос, но ответ хотелось бы узнать и осознать.

Пишу диплом, сам занимаюсь веб-разработкой, попутно иногда почитываю Макконнелла "Совершенный код: 2 издание", который пишет о конструировании конкретно программного обеспечения, его этапах и т.п. В веб-разработке большинство (если не все) этапов присутствуют... Но зайдя на [википедию](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5) я не убедился в том, что и веб-сайты являются программным обеспечением. Тогда что это, чем же они являются?

Comment: сайты сейчас это больше информационные ресурсы, но так же присутствуют сайты такие как c9.io например, которые являются оболочкой над серверной средой, а это уже полноценное IDE (т.е. ПО) для разработки. И таких достаточно много. Сейчас большинство выбирают веб приложения, ежели ПО ПК, т.к его легче поддерживать и обновлять

Comment: мне кажется что нельзя определять сайты как информационные ресурсы, т.к. игровые портали и браузерные игры туда не относятся, однако реализовываются +- одинаковым инструментом.

Comment: Почему это сайты не могут быть ПО? Вебсервер из одного [файла](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/master/web_servers/show_last_bash_quotes/main.py) на питоне

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Цитируем ту же вики - ПО, это

> все или часть программ, процедур, правил и соответствующей
>   документации системы обработки информации

Обрабатывает ли сайт информацию?

Старинные сайты Web 1.0, состоящие из одной страницы, программой является с большой натяжкой - он только объясняет браузеру, как правильно расположить контент на странице. Однако, даже на них водились элементы переработки информации - счетчики посещений и гостевые книги.

Современные сайты Web 2.0, предоставляют пользователю возможность самостоятельно управлять на них контентом: выполнять поиск, структурирование, публикацию материалов, разграничение доступа и так далее - то есть - перерабатывать информацию.

Вывод - Web 2.0 - полноценное ПО, Web 1.0 - ПО с большой натяжкой.

Comment: здесь задавали вопрос про web 2.0, - http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/548123/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-web-2-0 может пригодится .

Answer (score 0):

Я думаю, что сайты, сами по себе, не являются програмнным обеспечением, но включают его понятие в себя. Сайты - это совокупность контента и программного обеспечения. На мой взгляд можно провести такую аналогию, смотря телепередачу по телевизору, вы не называете ее телевизором, но тем не менее говорите говорите "смотрю телевизор".