# Что такое Web 2.0?

Tags: веб-программирование

К каким сущностям можно отнести выражение **Web 2.0** и по какому критерию? Существует ли стандарт (RFC), или другие общепринятые методики, по которым можно определить принадлежность к **Web 2.0**.
Достаточно ли для веб приложения быть одностраничником (SPA), чтобы называться **Web 2.0**?

Answer (score 2):

Стандарта, как такового, нет.
Ключевые факторы, определяющие принадлежность приложения к Web 2.0 - его дизайн, удобство пользования им, использование в его разработке современных технологий.

Это довольно расплывчатое понятие, которое и признают-то не все.

Comment: Лет эдак с пять назад, бытовало мнение, что Web2.0 это когда пользователи сами наполняют контент. Ну как здесь например.

Comment: Каждый понимает по-своему. И исходя из оценки этих субъективных "пониманий" уже можно относить(или не относить) приложение к Web 2.0.

Answer (score 2):

Как мне кажется под Web 2.0 часто понимается такое веб-приложение, которое на текущий момент использует все возможности современных вэб-технологий:

- возможность работать с сайтом в оффлайн режиме
- возможность использовать сайт людям с ограниченными возможностями
- правильное отображение на любом устройстве
- сегодня можно уже смело добавить технологию объёмных панорам - VR
- .....

Comment: То есть сайты, которые десять лет назад считались вебом 2.0, сегодня таковыми являться уже не будут?

Comment: @andreymal Нет же чёткого определения что веб 2.0 а что нет. В период бурного развития веб технологий , придумали термин, но сейчас он не актуален. Я попытался донести суть, что под ним понимают обычно.

Answer (score 1):

Web 1.0 -- пользователи не влияют на контент

Web 2.0 -- пользователи влияют на контент, и это не контролируется сайтовладельцем

Web 3.0 -- пользователи влияют на контент, и это контролируется сайтовладельцем

Comment: Какое-то крайне странное определение. Получается, Web 3.0 появился больше 20 лет назад с первым появлением премодерации?